# How to add a special Woocommerce “Buy Now” button?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I wish to add a "Buy now" button on product page, and redirect to checkout page after clicking it but without adding the product into the cart.

For example, if there are already products 1 and 2 in the cart , and I click the 'Buy now' button on another product page of 3 , 1 and 2 in the cart will be still in the cart and remain not checkout, Only 3 will be in the product list of the checkout page and also 3 is not adding into cart.

To be exact, I want something that works like this plugin:  https://www.storeapps.org/product/woocommerce-buy-now/ but it's a premium plugin and I want to do it for free

How can i do this guys?

Comment: hi real moise please check this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-simple-buy-now/

Comment: Hi vikrant zilpe, this one is hiding the add to cart  button. Can I have both buttons on the product?